# How to create new order states in magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-status, order-state

"processing", "complete", "new" are examples of the default Magento order state codes. but how to create custom order state

Comment: Accept the answer If you find my answer helpful@Nikhil

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149089/creating-new-order-states-programmatically-in-magento2/229948#229948

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating extension then you can use below script into your `InstallData.php` or `UpgradeData.php`

```
 $states = [
        'test' => [
            'label' => __('test'),
            'statuses' => ['test' => ['default' => '1']],
            'visible_on_front' => true,
        ],
    ];

    foreach ($states as $code => $info) {
        if (isset($info['statuses'])) {
            foreach ($info['statuses'] as $status => $statusInfo) {
                $data[] = [
                    'status' => $status,
                    'state' => $code,
                    'is_default' => is_array($statusInfo) && isset($statusInfo['default']) ? 1 : 0,
                ];
            }
        }
    }
    $setup->getConnection()->insertArray(
        $setup->getTable('sales_order_status_state'),
        ['status', 'state', 'is_default'],
        $data
    );
```

Just replace `test` with your order state code and `'statuses' => ['test' => ['default' => '1']],` replace with your order status.

You can find same script in below path,

`app\code\Magento\Sales\Setup\InstallData.php`